# Lift JSON: How to convert convert list of tuples to JsonAST?

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

The following code produces a List[JsonAst.JObject]:

```
val json = recommendations.map { r =>
  ("cardId" -> r._1) ~
  ("count" -> r._2)
}
```

This one doesn't. It produces List[(String, Int)]:

```
val json = recommendations.map { r =>
  (r._1.toString -> r._2)
}
```

How can I convert this List[(Int, Int)] into JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For org.json4s.json library**

Since `(r._1.toString -> r._2)` doesn't produce a JObject without the `~` operator, you need to lift it manually to JObject, which takes a list of Tuples as Parameter:

```
val json = recs.map { r =>
  JObject(List(JField(r._1, JInt(r._2))))
}
```

Produces:

```
List[JsonAST.JObject]
```

**EDIT for net.liftweb.json library**

```
val json = recs.map { r =>
  JObject(List(JField(r._1, JInt(r._2))))
}
```

**EDIT Both libraries allow the same syntax**

Comment: I get a type mismatch `found   : (Int, net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JInt)` but `required: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JField`

Comment: Okay apparently we use different libraries. My imports are:

`import org.json4s._ 
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._`

These were included in my dev stack.
Will check for yours.

Comment: @Wonko Edited accordingly

Comment: Had to use .toString for name parameter: `JObject(List(JField(r._1.toString, JInt(r._2))))`

Comment: @Wonko So you had an Integer in the first field of the tuple? Sorry didn't catch that from your question. But yes if you want a number as key, you need to .toString it. If it helped, please mark as accepted answer.